# How to deploy three config server instances for sharding in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, server, cluster-computing, sharding

I am a newbie in MongoDB. Also I have not much knowledge in networking and servers. I am trying to deploy sharded cluster in mongodb using [this article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/).

It says I need to deploy three configuration server instances and create data directories for each.
I can create a data directory using this command

```
mkdir /data/configdb
```

But how do I do this for all three of them?
Also I want to do this in only one machine.

Comment: Configuring a sharded cluster is a task for administrators, not software developers. I nominated your question for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: BTW three config server are recommended for production deployment. For testing, you can go for 1 config server, 1 query router and atleast 2 shard server. This article will help you: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sharded-cluster-in-mongodb-using-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [**dev** mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754736/how-to-deploy-three-config-server-instances-for-sharding-in-mongodb#comment49565677_30754736), for testing purposes a single *config server* is pretty much enough, and three *config servers* should be considered for production deployment.

But anyway, there is no problem creating separate directories for each *config server* on one machine. As you have mentioned, yes you can create directories, but data directory for any mongo instance (`mongod`, `configsvr`, etc.) is not limited to any path. So that means you can create separate directories and launch `mongod` config servers by specifying path for each:

```
$ mkdir /data/configdb1
$ mkdir /data/configdb2
$ mkdir /data/configdb3
$ mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/configdb1 ...
$ mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/configdb2 ...
$ mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/configdb3 ...
```